# Symfony2 throwing 404 inside kernel request event

Tags: php, symfony, events

I may be going about this completely the wrong way, but I have a onKernelRequest event setup which picks up the current domain (multi site on a single application), queries cache/db and stores this in the service for use by other controllers/services. This works perfectly.

Now if the domain isn't found, I'd like to throw a 404 error. Usually I'd just do the following in a controller:

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException('Not found!');
```

But this results in an uncaught exception in production, so I'm assuming due to the priority of the event (31).

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Not found!'
```

My current code (with logic removed for clarity), note I use JMSDiExtraBundle to configure services.

```
/**
 * @Service
 */
class CurrentDomainListener
{
    /**
     * @Observe("kernel.request", priority=31)
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        // find domain in cache/database...

        if (!$domain) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Not found!');
        }

        // store domain in service...
    }
}
```

My question is what would be the best way to display a 404 error when the domain doesn't exist?

Comment: You may want to catch that error too and return something useful.

Comment: That's kind of what I'm asking...

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Comment: As a quick fix I simply redirect to a 404 page. Don't like this but needed something which worked. $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('route_name')));

Comment: This could be useful. [Triggering redirect in event listener with onKernelException when 404 NotFoundHttpException occurs](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/xtjc/triggering-redirect-in-event-listener-with-on-kernel-exception-when-404-not-found-http-exception-occurs)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could return a 404 response instead of throwing an exception:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    // find domain in cache/database...

    if (!$domain) {
        $event->setResponse(new Response('Not found!', 404));
    }

    // store domain in service...
}
```

Comment: This is not the right solution, because the 404 is not handled properly by Symfony and won't display the 404 page, but a simple white page displaying "Not found!".

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but I had the same problem and this worked for me:

When an exception is thrown and `ExceptionListener` catches it, it adds the exception to request attributes and replays the request. This causes the listeners to be notified again, and they will throw another exception for the same reason as the first time.

I solved (worked around?) this problem by checking if there's no exception set in the request in my listeners:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if ($request->attributes->has('exception')) {
        return;
    }

    // ...
    if ($somethingWasWrong) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }
}
```

Now the condition for failure is not checked when the exception has already been thrown, and the exception will be handled appropriately.

EDIT: I looked into Symfony listeners and they check if the current request is the master request:

```
if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: You could just omit checking attributes, assuring to be on the master request does work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

you can render php not found

```
if(!$domain)
   die(http_response_code(404));
```

this way if domain not found then showed default "page not found" of browser

i think this can be better